# Can't verify the form details with database using php

Tags: php, html, database, forms

I created this login page form

```
<form name="loginform" method="post" action="home1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="Form1"  onsubmit="return Validateloginform(this)">
    <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="form1">
    <div id="wb_Text14" style="position:absolute;left:44px;top:13px;width:412px;height:38px;z-index:0;text-align:left;">
        <span style="color:#000080;font-family:'Comic Sans MS';font-size:27px;"> <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; LOGIN  </strong></span></div>
    <div id="wb_Text15" style="position:absolute;left:29px;top:75px;width:122px;height:27px;z-  index:1;text-align:left;">
        <span style="color:#000080;font-family:'Comic Sans MS';font-size:19px;"><strong> USERNAME</strong></span></div>
    <input type="text" id="Editbox6"     style="position:absolute;left:187px;top:75px;width:267px;height:28px;line-height:28px;z-index:2;" name="username" value="">
    <div id="wb_Text16"  style="position:absolute;left:34px;top:129px;width:125px;height:27px;z- index:3;text-align:left;">
        <span style="color:#000080;font-family:'Comic Sans MS';font-size:19px;"> <strong>PASSWORD</strong></span></div>
    <input type="password" id="Editbox7"   style="position:absolute;left:187px;top:129px;width:267px;height:28px;line-height:28px;z-index:4;" name="password" value="">
    <input type="submit" id="Button1" name="submit" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left:142px;top:223px;width:195px;height:52px;z- index:5;">
</form>
```

My php code is

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['formid'] == 'form1') {
        $mysql_server = 'localhost';
        $mysql_username = 'root';
        $mysql_password = '';
        $mysql_database = 'register';
        $mysql_table = 'users';

        $db = mysqli_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
        if (!$db) {
            die('Failed to connect to database server! <br>' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        mysqli_select_db($db, $mysql_database) or die('Failed to select database<br>' . mysqli_connect_error());
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            header('Location: home1.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            $error = "Incorrect username and password";
        }
    }
?>
```

I don't know what is wrong  with this  code . Everything seems fine . It isn't verifying data that is entered in the login form with the data that is present in the database . Even if I type wrong password or wrong username or even don't type anything and just press the submit button , it redirects me successfully to the desired page . My registration form and code works fine and the data is being successfully entered in the database through the form .

My desired page's name is home1.php  . I have both the registration form and the login form on the same webpage . Earlier , I had the php code of both the registration form and login form on the same page . At that   time when I ran this code , it used to redirect me to the same page itself . My teacher asked me to put the php code of the login form in the desired webpage i.e,home1.php . I put it , then when I press the submit button , it redirects me to the home1.php page( my desired page) but I have figured out that even if I don't enter anything in the login form and press submit then it also redirects me to the desired page and if I put the username and password that is not present in the database , it again redirects me to the desired page . 
I then put the login form php code in a different file and then tried to access the home1.php page but the same problem was there . Please help me . I don't know what to do .
Thank you !

Comment: You shouldn't store the user's password in session, it's quite unsafe

Comment: yes . Actually , I am new to PHP and this is the first login form and database connection that I have done . I will learn about it more in future .

Comment: Are you saving password as user entered means you are not using any encryption or here you forgot to decrypt password?

Comment: No . I am first making a user register through my registration form . The data entered by the user is goinng to my database . Then I am making the user login through his registered username and password which is not working properly . Even if I type a username or password which was not registered , I am successful being redirected to the home page.

Answer (score 2):

You have several errors in your code.

You're always being redirected to home1.php because you have in your form

```
<form name="loginform" method="post" action="home1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="Form1"  onsubmit="return Validateloginform(this)">
```

This will execute your code on home1.php file, you should store your login code in another page, lets say loginPage.php, therefore your form should be:

```
<form name="loginform" method="post" action="loginPage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="Form1"  onsubmit="return Validateloginform(this)">
```

You should also change your code to something like this:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['formid'] == 'form1') {
        $mysql_server = 'localhost';
        $mysql_username = 'root';
        $mysql_password = '';
        $mysql_database = 'register';
        $mysql_table = 'users';

        $db = mysqli_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
        if (!$db) {
            die('Failed to connect to database server! <br>' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";

        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1 && $row["password"] == $password) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location: home1.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            $error = "Incorrect username and password";
        }
    }
?>
```

The code above is working correctly.

You should also consider using some hash functions on the register and login page as it's highly insecure to store plain text passwords in your database.

Comment: okay . I stored the code in a new file called loginForm.php and changed the code like you have told me . Now , it redirects me to the loginForm.php but from there I am not being directed to the home1.php page  .

Comment: Have you checked if the combination of username / password your entering is the correct one? I've just tested that code and it's working fine here.

Comment: yes . I did for both . I first checked it with cirrect usernamepassword combinatuin and then with the wrong combination but the result is the same . It opens  a blank page of the file loginForm.php .

Comment: I seems to me that the code is not being executed here . I don't know why ? I have tried everything .

Comment: What are you using to run the php script?

Comment: I am using the xampp server